# QTranslator not installing persistently in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm developing an app using PyQt5 and I'm encountering a problem related to the i18n functions of the framework, specifically all the QTranslator related code.

As the docs say, I'm using a QTranslator object to load the compiled .qm file, like this:

```
tr_object = QTranslator()
tr_object.load(current, "lang")
QCoreApplication.installTranslator(tr_object)
```

The problem is that it seems to only install it "temporarily", i.e. if I call translate() immediately afterwards it works, but then it's as if the translator gets uninstalled immediately.

My current (ugly) workaround is to replace the translate() function in QCoreApplication by a wrapper that re-installs the translator every time, but that creates a very large overhead that slows down everything.

I have also tried using my instance of QApplication instead of the static QCoreApplication, same issue. The QT_TR_NOOP macros don't work either.

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh. Well. Haha. I feel stupid. Could you put your comment in an answer? That way I'll be able to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt doesn't take ownership of the translator, so you need to keep a reference to it on the python side to stop it being garbage-collected.